# Java не работает try catch из-за scanner

Tags: java, scanner

Не могу исправить ошибку из-за сканнера в методе "nacistVolbu()", но она работает правильно, если не использовать метод "upravitZaznam()". Подскажите пожалуйста почему. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public class alp_taskC {

private static final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // hlavni ridici smycka programu
    boolean konecProgramu = false;
    while (!konecProgramu) {
        // vypsat menu
        vypisHlavniMenuProgramu();
        // nacist volbu uzivatel
        int volbaUzivatele = nacistVolbu();
        // provest akci pozadovanou uzivatelem
        switch (volbaUzivatele) {
            case 0:
                konecProgramu = true;
                break;
            case 2:
                upravitZaznam();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Zadana neplatna volba");
        }
    }
}

private static void vypisHlavniMenuProgramu() {
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Hlavni menu programu");
    //System.out.println("1. Pridat zaznam zaku");
    System.out.println("2. Upravit nektere casti zaznamu zaku");  //исправить список в файле
    //System.out.println("3. Odstranit nektere ze zaznamu zaku");
    //System.out.println("4. Zobrazit seznam");
    //System.out.println("5. Vytvorit novou sadu zaznamu");
    System.out.println("0. Konec programu");
}

private static int nacistVolbu() {
    int volba = -1;
    System.out.print("Zadej zvolenou polozku menu: ");
    try {
        volba = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        // neplatna volba
        volba = -1;
    }
//        finally {
//                sc.nextLine();
//        }
    return volba;
}

//    private static ArrayList<String> lidi = new ArrayList<String>();
//    private static ArrayList<Integer> znamka = new ArrayList<Integer>();



private static void upravitZaznam() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    try {
        System.out.println("Jaky radek chcete zmenit?");
        int radek = scan.nextInt() - 1;
        new alp_taskC().zmenitRadek("ibrayev/src/seznamZaku.txt", radek);
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Opraveno");
    }
    scan.close();
}

private void zmenitRadek(String file, int line) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Zmenit na: ");

    String newLine = scan.nextLine();

    scan.close();

    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String temp = "";
    String[] result = null;
    int pocetRadku = 0;
    try {
        int iter = 0;

        while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null) pocetRadku++;

        br = null;
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        result = new String[pocetRadku];

        while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (iter != line) result[iter] = temp;
            else result[iter] = newLine;

            iter++;
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file));

        int i = 0;

        while (pocetRadku != 0) {
            pw.println(result[i]);
            i++;
            pocetRadku--;
        }

        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Еще актуально ?

Comment: зачем так много так много кода приводить, кто в нем разбираться будет?

Comment: Да еще актуален. Я убрал лишний код.

Comment: все вполне ужасно... если проблема еще актуальна, скажите, какая цель этого кода и что в файле, который читается?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ как исправить данную ошибку. Я соединил методы "upravitZaznam()" и "zmenitRadek()".

```
public static void upravitZaznam(){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Jaky radek chcete zmenit?");
    int radek = scan.nextInt() -1;

    System.out.println("Zmenit radek na: ");

    String newLine = scan.next();

    BufferedReader buffReader = null;
    try {
        buffReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("ibrayev/src/seznamZaku.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String temp = "";
    String[] result = null;
    int howRows = 0;
    try {
        int iter = 0;

        while ((temp = buffReader.readLine()) != null) howRows++;

        buffReader = null;
        buffReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("ibrayev/src/seznamZaku.txt"));

        result = new String[howRows];

        while ((temp = buffReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (iter != radek) result[iter] = temp;
            else result[iter] = newLine;

            iter++;
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        buffReader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("ibrayev/src/seznamZaku.txt"));

        int i = 0;

        while (howRows != 0) {
            pw.println(result[i]);
            i++;
            howRows--;
        }

        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

В блоке finally читаете следующую строку с какой целью？ Она всегда выполняется, даже если там ничего нет. Блок finally выполняется всегда независимо есть ошибка или нет.

Comment: даже если ее удалить, программа все равно выдает ошибку.

Comment: с той же ошибкой？надо вывести текст ошибки в консоль хотя бы а не прятать ее

Comment: да, с той же. Выходит ошибка из-за сканнера в методе "nacistVolbu()", но если не использовать метод "upravitZaznam()", то метод работает правильно.

Comment: т.е. вы удаляете строку в которой ошибка - а ошибка в ней же？ код точно перекомпилировался？

Comment: Я не очень понимаю вас. Если я удали метод "upravitZaznam()", то программа работает правильно и метод "nacistVolbu()" не выдает ошибку.

Comment: После nextInt() нужно считывать символ конца строки. Добавьте sc.nextline();